# Laravel orderBy not correctly ordering

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table called `users` and I have row called `ELO_points`.

Some users have "-10" ELO_points and some have "25".

Sometimes `orderBy` not working correctly.

My controller:

```
$users = User::orderBy('ELO_points', 'DESC')->take(5)->get();
```

My view:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    @if($loop->iteration == 1)
        <div class="right-points">{!! $user->ELO_points !!}</div>
    </li>
    @endif
    @if($loop->iteration == 2)
        <div class="right-points">{!! $user->ELO_points !!}</div>
    </li>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Any help why my ordering not showing like normal from -10 to 10?

Comment: Can you let us know what is meant by  `@if($loop->iteration == 1)` and  `@if($loop->iteration == 2)` ?

Comment: Don't you have those values saved as the strings instead of the signed integers?

Comment: @vivek_23 i taking first of foreach and second by using `@if($loop->iteration == 1)` That becouse i need custom text for first foreach item :)

Comment: @MyndeMindaugelis Best way to debug this is to print `$users` after the eloqunet query itself and show us what you get(by editing your post). Like Dawid said, are the values stored as integers or is it varchar in the DB table?

Comment: `Any help why my ordering not showing like normal from -10 to 10?`, you're using `DESC` so it should go from 10 to -10...shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the following query.

```
$query = "CAST(ELO_points AS INT) DESC";
$users = User::orderByRaw($query)->take(5)->get();
```